# Why my Galileo isn't getting a IP address?

Tags: ethernet, arduino-galileo

I have an Ethernet cable connected to my router. I connected the other end to my laptop and got a successful connection. When I plug it into my Arduino Galileo gen2, even with Ethernet port green light on, I got nothing when I run this:

```
delay(1000);
system("ifconfig eth0 > /dev/ttyGS0");
```

This is my output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:41 Base address:0x8000
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have no MAC address (HWaddr).  This usually means you have a driver problem.  That might be why you aren't getting an address.

Comment: This might point you in the right direction; https://communities.intel.com/thread/45455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why, but after I initialized the Ethernet interface`ifconfig eth0 up` it started working properly. I don't know why this time this command was needed and the others didn't.